# S3 Upload via CURL fails when triggered via cronjob

Tags: bash, curl, amazon-s3, cron

I'm using a script `dump-to-s3.sh` to put database dumps in a S3 bucket.
When triggered manually it works perfectly but when I trigger it via  this cron (as root crontab) it fails with the following error message:

**crontab**

```
31 12 * * * /home/dokku/.mongodb/dump-to-s3.sh
```

**error from CURL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
   <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
   Check your key and signing method.</Message>...
```

**dump-to-s3.sh**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
#cd to dump-folder
cd /dump/folder
file="mydump.tar.gz"

bucket="mybucket"
resource="/${bucket}/dumps/${file}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
s3Secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`

curl -X PUT -T "${file}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/dumps/${file}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need to run `bash` manually, e.g.

```
/bin/bash /home/dokku/.mongodb/dump-to-s3.sh
```

The `-en` options for `echo` don't work in the regular shell; it might just be a bash extension.

In `sh`:

```
$ sh
sh-3.2$ echo -en foo
-en foo
sh-3.2$
```

In `bash`:

```
$ bash
bash-3.2$ echo -en foo
foobash-3.2$
```

Comment: It works now. Thanks a lot, both for the script and the answer here.